# What are "sequence point"/"sequenced-before" rules in Rust?

Tags: c++, rust

What are the rules in Rust, analogous to the rules, described here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order for C++?

For now I found empirically, that
1) Arguments of functions are evaluated in direct order
2) All built-in operations with side effects (=, +=, -=, etc.) return unit, so it is hard (but possible) to compose expressions, which would show UB in C++.
One example:

```
let mut a = 1i;
let b = 2i;
let c = 3i;
let d = (a = b) == (a = c); // What is a? (a is actually 3)
```

3) It seems like function calls are sequenced as in C++
4) It seems like built-in operations are sequenced as if they were function (method) calls, i.e. order of evaluation is tied to the operator precedence

Are my conclusions correct? What is the exact evaluation model?

Comment: I set out to answer this, but after crafting http://is.gd/IkU043 I think I had better do something else for a while…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe it has been explicitly defined, my grepping of [the manual](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/rust.html) didn't turn up anything. However, I can guarantee that these things will not be undefined behaviour (Rust explicitly avoids UB outside `unsafe` code), and I would be surprised if it were anything but "left-to-right", that is, the order you have deduced. Although, the resolution to [#6268](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6268) may result in methods evaluating the receiver last (or maybe not, this is just one possibility).

I opened [#15300](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15300).

---

Btw, if you are investigating this, you can make the compiler split out pretty control flow graphs with the *precise* order of evaluation (NB. this is all internal APIs, and so cannot be relied on, is more likely than normal to make the compiler crash, and doesn't hide the compiler implementation details: it's mainly designed for people working on `rustc`).

*As @pnkfelix points out, the compiler isn't using the CFG for code generation (as of 2014-07-02), meaning the CFG isn't guaranteed to be exactly accurate.*

E.g. taking a stripped down version of one of @ChrisMorgan's examples:

```
fn foo(_: (), x: int) -> int {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    { // A
        a * foo(a = 3, a)
    };
}
```

We want the compiler to split out a control flow graph of the statements/expressions within some block (i.e. `{ ... }`), which can be done via the `--pretty flowgraph=<nodeid>` option to the compiler, but for that we need to have the ID of our block of interest. In this case, the block we want is `A`. To get the id compile with `rustc --pretty expanded,identified` (note that just using `identified` is a pointless relic: the ids now only get assigned after macro expansion):

```
#![feature(phase)]
#![no_std]
#![feature(globs)]
#[phase(plugin, link)]
extern crate std = "std#0.11.0-pre";
extern crate native = "native#0.11.0-pre";
use std::prelude::*;
fn foo(_ /* pat 7 */: (), x /* pat 11 */: int) -> int { (x /* 15 */) } /*
block 14 */ /* 4 */

fn main() {
    let mut a /* pat 22 */ = (1 /* 23 */);
    ({
         ((a /* 28 */) *
             ((foo /* 30
                  */)(((a /* 32 */) = (3 /* 33 */) /* 31 */), (a /* 34 */)) /*
                 29 */) /* 27 */)
     } /* block 26 */ /* 25 */);
} /* block 18 */ /* 16 */
```

Lots of icky internals junk, but the thing we need is there in a comment `/* block 26 */`. `rustc --pretty flowgraph=26` gives a dot file, which renders to the following. You can consult the identifier annotated source above to work exactly what each expression is (the `id = ..` bit):

[image: CFG]

(sorry for length, obviously this code had no branching and so is just a long chain of operations.)

FWIW, that expression evaluates to `9`, while I was expecting `3` (and the control flow graph confirms that the isolated `a` on the LHS is being evaluated after the RHS, including the `a = 3` there). I've raised this on #15300 (*e:* and now [isolated it to a strange difference in evaluation order](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15300#issuecomment-47653746)).

Comment: Things like [*Operator precedence* from the reference manual](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#operator-precedence) are relevant, though certainly not complete.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. If you need it, I can probably produce some short formal text based on C++ standard's definitions and Rust's expected semantics.

Comment: Note that the code generation step in rustc is current driven by the abstract syntax tree, *not* the constructed control flow graph.  (The control flow graph is used as the basis for some static analyses.)  This means that bugs can creep in, where the executed code behaves differently from what the control flow graph predicts.  Example: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14962

Comment: @pnkfelix, oh! Whoops, I guess my answer is now wrong... I'll clarify.

Comment: New link for [Operator precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: Is there a TL:DR on this issue yet, or a newer duplicate?  Like is `fib(n-2, memo_cache) + fib(n-1, memo_cache)` guaranteed to do the `n-2` call first, searching backwards 2 steps at a time for the last hit in the manually implemented memoization cache?